# Fast way to get the current Calendar object in Java

Tags: java, time, calendar

Given a method that needs to use the values of the current day/month/year on every invocation and which is invoked several (millions or more) times per second, is there any faster way of implementing that functionality, other than creating a `Calendar` object for the current time on every invocation?

Using `Calendar.getInstance()` or `calendar.setTime()` (with time field recalculation) is overly expensive to do many times per second.

Standard Java solutions are preferable (e.g., over using third party libraries).

Comment: Nonsense.  It's a nano optimization that I'm certain you can't measure.  The rest of your code is likely to be far more inefficient.  Profile your code and fix the big problems.  Don't bother with this until you have data saying it's a big problem.

Comment: Like duffymo says, do you have actual numbers backing this theory up?

Comment: Maybe you should post the "many times per second." code

Comment: The `Calendar.getInstance()` method achieves roughly 1,000,000 to 2,000,000 invocations per second in a particular test system. There are use cases requiring many more invocations per second than those figures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current date/time, I find that `LocalDate.now()` is faster than `Calendar.getInstance()`. The LocalDate class can be found in the `java.time` package, which is new since Java 8 (Of course, if you want to maintain compatibility with old Java versions, that may not be an option).

Comment: You'll find the whole java.time package is much easier to use than trying to manipulate a calendar instance anyway.

Comment: My upvote for the hint to `LocalDate` although I give different reasons in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution within the scope of standard java (no 3rd party-libraries) is using the class `LocalDate`. So far this answer is identical to that of @Chronio, but I differ in use. The factory method `now()` cannot be so quick because it exploits the system timezone - maybe even using a synchronized approach anywhere in the depth of `TimeZone.getDefault()`.

But the class `LocalDate` is very quick if you use its factory methods with arguments of year, month and day-of-month. Here you are just setting the state members without any timezone calculation and without any calculation of gregorian calendar math (okay only quick year-dependent length-of-month-check is involved). Just see the source code.

Answer (score 1):

use the Date, instead of Calendar class it will give you the current date

Comment: The Date class is marked as deprecated and should not be used. Use LocalDate instead, which is introduced in Java 8.